# AWS How to revert merge made in pipeline

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, rollback, revert

I merged our branches and it messed with some validation. And since then I cannot figure out how to correctly rollback. I tried to use -- git revert ... -- however it has been changing one file in the revert but the other files stay as the most recent changes. Can I manually revert the branch on the repository or at least on the aws site?

So this branch is as oldas if no changes were made today

Comment: In general, in Git, you can clone the repo locally on a machine, fix up branches however you'd like, and when you're happy with it, push out your new commits. If you need specific help with `git revert`, then provide more details with what you're trying to do, the commands you tried, and what the results were.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I learnt the difference between revert and reset this day. I eventually used reset as it took it back to a 0 point rather then reverting only the file changed in that day.